# How to disable Logs for flutter_sound package?

Tags: flutter, logging

I'm using flutter_sound package for recording and playing audios. Default log level is pretty annoying.

I've tried

```
FlutterSoundRecorder myRecorder = FlutterSoundRecorder(logLevel: Level.debug);
```

but `Level` is undefined here. It's not present in flutter_sound package (flutter_sound is already imported).

```
import 'package:flutter_sound/flutter_sound.dart';
```

I'm unable to figure out how to import it? Version of flutter_sound package is

```
  flutter_sound: ^9.2.13
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/logger/latest/logger/Level.html

Comment: It didn't work as dev dependency.

Comment: @AmeerHamza It should be a regular dependency, not a dev dependency.

Comment: @pskink I got your point. I thought that logger package should be a dev dependency. As a dev dependency it wasn't working. Adding as regular dependency did the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the log level of the `flutter_sound` package as follows:

1. First, you need to add the logging package to your project by command:

   ```
   flutter pub add logger
   ```
2. Then, import the Level enum by adding the following import statement:

   ```
   import 'package:logger/logger.dart';
   ```
3. Finally, set the log level to the intended value in your code:

   ```
   final recorder = FlutterSoundRecorder(logLevel: Level.nothing);
   final player = FlutterSoundPlayer(logLevel: Level.nothing);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As per flutter_sound doc, you can set loglevel as

```
await myRecorder.setLogLevel(Level.debug);
```

For detailed info, you can visit their [documentation](https://flutter-sound.canardoux.xyz/tau_api_recorder_setLogLevel.html#setloglevel)

Comment: The problem is I can't access 'Level' enum

Comment: If the problem persists, take a look at my answer. @AmeerHamza

Answer (score 0):

You can import logger

```dart
import 'package:logger/logger.dart';
```